# Entity Framework compiled query container?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I figure the following is either a good idea, in which case it's likely someone here can point me to the code that implements it. Or a dumb idea in which case someone will explain why and save me the wasted frustration.

Is it possible to create a container for each of my Entity Framework queries where the first time it is called, the query is compiled, and the executed. And then on subsequent times, it calls the now already compiled query?

Preferably in a way that it is created right inline in the method where it's used so it's to a large degree invisible (making crafting the queries similar to not using this container)?

Comment: EF Core already caches compilations for the same expression, I think this is a premature optimization.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean exactly by "compiling query"? Do you mean translating the Linq expressions/IQueryable extension method calls to SQL? Is that a part you have found to be slow? Or do you mean compiling the textual query in the database server?

Comment: @Charlieface I've read several blogs saying they switched to compiled queries and got between a 10% and 50% improvement. But if EF does this for me then yeah - no need.

Comment: Note that all queries are compiled on first use, even when you use `EF.CompileQuery`. But using `EF.CompileQuery` skips building an expression tree then comparing it to the queries that have been seen / cached.

Comment: (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant#compiled-queries)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Reading that it looks like compiled queries are a big win. And that is with the EF caching.

Comment: In other words, EF Core already has a compiled query container https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Query/Internal/CompiledQueryBase.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How internally LINQ translation works:

**Standard behavior:**

1. The translator checks the cache for an existing translation of a similar expression tree.
2. If it finds one, it uses the cached SQL and mapper to execute the query with the given parameters.
3. If not, it translates the LINQ expression, generates the SQL and the mapper, caches them, and executes the query.

**Compiled query behavior:**

1. The translator checks a **field** for a precompiled translation.
2. If it finds one, it uses the precompiled SQL and mapper to execute the query with the given parameters.
3. If not, it translates the LINQ expression, generates the SQL and the mapper, stores them in the **field**, and executes the query.

The main difference between these algorithms is that the **compiled query** does not search the cache for an existing translation of the expression tree, but only looks in the **field**. Searching the cache can be costly depending on the cache state and the expression tree complexity - see [ExpressionEqualityComparer](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/0ee3ac8de9349f7f9571ed1e50dbb65f9fee3734/src/EFCore/Query/ExpressionEqualityComparer.cs) for how expressions are compared.

That's why **compiled queries** are faster.

What you are trying to do is replicate the **standard behavior**, which would require searching the cache again. This does not make sense in the current EF Core implementation.

Comment: To confirm, writing explicit compiled queries to the reuse is worth the effort though - correct?

Comment: CompiledQueries have a little bit cumbersome syntax and they have limitations, use them only when you need maximum performance.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I suggest adding your comment to the answer.